# Windows Runtime Component C++ Struct/Classes Returned to UWP

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, windows-runtime

I have inherited a C++ code base and need to create a new front end.  I was hoping to use Windows Universal Runtime Component to combine the UWP to the C++ code.  I have had a some success with primitive types and returning them from C++ to the C# code behind.  However when i attempt anything non primitive I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C3986   'functionName': signature of public member contains native
>   type 'C++Class::Struct' (compiling source file
>   Class.cpp)    WRC wrc1\class.h

Is there any way to decorate the C++ classes/structs in a way they would be returnable to the UWP projects C# code behind?

Answer (score 0):

For a struct to be allowed as a public member of a class, you should mark it `public value struct`.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-cpp#method-that-returns-a-custom-value-struct) is an example of returning custom struct.

```
namespace CppComponent
{
    // Custom struct
    public value struct PlayerData
    {
        Platform::String^ Name;
        int Number;
        double ScoringAverage;
    };

    public ref class Player sealed
    {
    private:
        PlayerData m_player;
    public:
        property PlayerData PlayerStats
        {
            PlayerData get(){ return m_player; }
            void set(PlayerData data) {m_player = data;}
        }
    };
}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-cpp#ccx-built-in-types-library-types-and-windows-runtime-types) has a lot of info, so it might be worth browsing for more info.